# MergeSort in python

Tags: python, sorting, mergesort

```
def merge(A,l,m,r):

    i = l
    j = m+1
    new = []

    while i <= m and j <= r:
        if A[i] <= A[j]:
            new.append(A[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            new.append(A[j])
            j += 1

    while i <= m:
        new.append(A[i])
        i += 1
   
    while j <= r:
        new.append(A[j])
        j += 1

    return new
```

This function doesn't work due to an error, can you help me to understand what is the error and how to fix it?

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the suspect values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?  It seems that you've decided to work with code from somewhere else that you don't understand, and haven't yet investigated.  "Explain this code to me" -- before you've traced the code for yourself -- is off-topic here.

Comment: Most of all, please explain *exactly* what you don't understand from the output you get when you trace this code. Include that trace in your MRE.

Comment: Are you sure you're reproduced the code that comment was attached to correctly? Because it would make more sense attacked to `m = l+(r-l)//2` (where there's no `1`, only two lowercase `L`s).

Comment: You keep referring to "error", but you post no error, so there's nothing to "reproduce".  You don't show a value and execution trace up to the problem point.  You say that you don't understand why you get the error, but you do not show the effort required to *try* to understand the error.  Stack Overflow is a spot repair site, not a general-purpose tutorial desk.

Comment: @Blckknght I think `l+(r-l)//2` is correct, because it's a very common trick for getting a midpoint without overflow.  Totally unnecessary in Python, because Python integers can't overflow.

Comment: I think the trick is you should change the array `A` inside the function `merge()` instead of making the `new` array and return it. I see no line where the return of the function `merge()` is assigned to some variable (like `A = merge(A)`). This return doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement doesn't make sense:

```
return new
```

Since you nowhere use the return of the function. So the function `merge()` does nothing.

I believe you need to change the array `A` directly inside the function. No need to create and return the `new` array.